# How do you calculate direction of velocity of a circle bouncing off another static circle?

Tags: java, geometry

I've got code for two moving circles to bounce off each other properly, but when applying the same code for the situation where one of the two moving circles is static and does not move, the moving circle seems to orbit the static one. How can I fix this?

Comment: I don't think anyone can be realistically expected to answer you unless you give more information, enough to make this question answerable.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your code?

Comment: @Hovercraft it's actually pretty straightforward if you've ever written a 2D physics engine. :-)

Comment: @glowcoder there is no way to understand why the OP's code results in one circle orbiting the other without seeing the code ...

Comment: @belisarius what his code is is irrelevant because it doesn't work. What's probably happening is he is constantly bouncing off the static circle (it's still within collision threshold, probably) which causes it to bounce again, and again, and again. Seen it happen myself designing a 2d top down game. Granted that's just an educated guess at why it's broken. But the solution I outline below is (in my experience) superior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have code for a circle bouncing off a wall, you can approximate it by finding the line that would be tangent to the static circle at the point of contact between the circles and pretending the moving circle bounced off a wall that runs along that line.

Comment: The line would be tangent to both circles, wouldn't it?

Comment: It seems that it would be yes. I'd have to double check the math on that, to be certain.

Comment: Im pretty certain that if you know the impact point on either circle you can calculate the tangent from that and it will be the same for either circles. that is, they will always collide at a point where their tangents are equal (or is that inverse)?

Comment: It seems to me that any collision between circles would occur at a point where they are tangent to each other. I don't have the theorem or proof in front of me but I believe that's the case.

Comment: @glowcoder two circles touching each other are always tangent.

Comment: A wall will not move after the collision, while a static circle will. That changes the resulting vectors

Comment: A static circle won't move. A dynamic circle with 0 speed will move. I interpreted a static circle to be "bolted down" or as the OP put it, "one of the two moving circles is static and does not move." He does say "two moving circles" but I interpreted that to be in reference to the fact that his existing function expects two moving circles, which is not the case.

Comment: @belisarius I expect that to be true, I simply don't have a proof or theorem to cite in front of me. In any case, it's irrelevant to the point at hand. What is tangent to the circle in motion doesn't matter.

Comment: +1 I think your approach is correct, but the collision is along the normal components of the velocities.

Comment: @glowcoder: It is relevant, since this makes calculating the "bounce-off-pseudo-wall line" much easier. We simply take the line orthogonal to the connecting line of both centers, at the right distance.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but I don't know how to bounce a circle off a diagonal wall

Comment: @Rahat calculate the angle between the wall and your vector, call it `t` (assume `t <= 90`, since if it were more, it would be closer to the other wall) and your resultant vector is `t` from the other side of the wall. Your resultant vector will have rotated `180 - 2*t` degrees. It's actually the same as bouncing off a regular wall.

Comment: It makes sense on paper, but I have absolutely no clue on how to program that, since all I have are the two center positions of the circles and their two velocity vectors.

Answer (score 2):

The article [*2-Dimensional Elastic Collisions*](http://www.vobarian.com/collisions/) offers a vector approach to the problem. In particular, "The tangential components of the velocities are not changed by the collision because there is no force along the line tangent to the collision surface. The normal components of the velocities undergo a one-dimensional collision," which conserves momentum and kinetic energy. There's a Java implementation [here](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/kineticmodel).